# Error when testing Factory toBeDefined

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

```
describe('Tickers Factory:', function() {
    var tickersFactory, tickerContainer, tickerType, chartIsReady;

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('tickersFactory');
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(_tickersFactory_) {
        tickersFactory = _tickersFactory_;
    }));

    it('tickersFactory should be defined', function() {
        expect(tickersFactory).toBeDefined();
    });
});
```

I'm trying to test if my `tickersFactory` service is defined, I have Jasmine running fine, however the above code throws the following error:

[image]

---

#### TickersFactory

```
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/**
* @name tickersFactory
* @namespace Factories
* @desc Stores the global ticker and ticker type
*/

var tickersFactory = angular
    .module('tickersFactory', [])
    .factory('TickersFactory', factory);

factory.$inject = [
    '$rootScope',
    'ApiFactory',
    'GetTickersFactory'
 ];

function factory(
    $rootScope,
    ApiFactory,
    GetTickersFactory) {

    /** Init TickersFactory scope */
    /** ----------------------------------------------------------------- */
    var tickerContainer = {},
        tickerType      = {},
        chartIsReady    = false;

    var tickersFactory = {
        returnChartReady : returnChartReady,
        storeTicker      : storeTicker,
        getTicker        : getTicker,
        storeTickerType  : storeTickerType,
        getTickerType    : getTickerType,
        initTickersPanel : initTickersPanel
    };

    return tickersFactory;
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function returnChartReady() {
        return chartIsReady;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the minimal definition of the module + the factory declaration?

Comment: Thanks, just did! Oh I'm also using webpack, and everything is inside of bundle.js does that help?

Comment: should not matter. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factory that you're testing is `_TickersFactory_` so you need to inject it using `_TickersFactory_`_ not `_tickersFactory_`.

From the image it's a little hard to tell but it seems you're getting [Error: $injector:unpr
Unknown Provider](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr)

Comment: I'm surprised you're not getting unknown provider for the ```_tickersFactory_``` typo.

Comment: Actually, you are: there is $injector:unpr error on the screenshot.

Comment: @estus just saw it, good thing for the mini error code there :) unpr

Comment: I renamed it, still the same error :( however so the $injector error, means I need to inject `ApiFactory` first? Trying that next...

Comment: You need to make available any factories/services/etc that your tested factory requires. Either mock them or load the module they belong to.